# How to import data from excel or csv file to MySql using C# Winform?

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, winforms, csv

I'm really a newbie one.

I wanted to import data from excel or CSV file to MySQL using C#. 
I just need a button and then, viola! It should insert automatically to MySQL database.

I only know how the structure of my excel file and my MySQL database table looks like. Just don't know how to import it.

Please help. As always, thank you!

Comment: What research have you done so far? You just need to 2 google searches Read Excel with C# and MySQL Insert

Comment: we can not code it for you but there are lots of sources thanks to StackOverFlow.
1-) read from [Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)
2-) insert data to [MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604216/how-i-can-insert-data-in-the-mysql-database)

you could have done this searches before asking this question.

Comment: I already know how to read or open the excel file. I just don't know what command string to use and how it will be executed by c# after opening the file.

Comment: And I don't know what query to use.

Comment: @EugeneGanancial This site has plenty of answered questions about doing what you want. Try the search bar ;)

Comment: @mmushtaq that's a horrible dupe ref imo

Comment: @Drew This question also contains a well explained answer as well as contains [Source Link](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/10/import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using.html) for more details

Comment: @mmushtaq it is the wrong server type, plus it loops. So basically that reference is like a plane going down in flames your ref [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759302) ... which is wrong

Comment: and imo, the SO also trying to accomplish same thing which is mentioned in this question.

Comment: It is the wrong server type, wrong technology stack, and even if it was right, it is 20 to 50 times slower

Comment: To make it simplier. Just wanted to do something like this, but in MySQL commands. The video is in MSSQL.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WF6y4FN-dg0
As always, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to start you off.. but you could've found this if you *actually* searched Stack Exchange or Google. Also since you commented that you already know how to read an Excel file... here's a start to insert the data.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

cont string connectInfo = "Server=yourServer;Database=yourDatabase;UID=yourUsername;Password=yourPassword";

var query = "insert into yourTable (column, column, column..) Values(@column1, @column2, @column3)";

using (var connect = new MySqlConnection(connectInfo)) {
 connect.Open();
 using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connect) {
   cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@column1", "something");
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column2", "something");
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column3", "something");
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 } 
}
```

Comment: I'm getting there, but maybe I should use bulk insert. Could you help me more please? Thanks!

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it. Often the csv has tens of thousands of rows. Or more. You must not have done much testing and googling yourself :p

Comment: @Drew well i did said it was a start for the OP not the solution. :) maybe u should read better

Comment: It is not even a start. It is horrible ! (hugs)

Comment: @Drew then give him a better start Mr. Smarty Pants:)

Comment: I did. I have a mysql hammer and I closed the question to a dupe target